# struct.unpack_from() buffer reading issue with data longer than 255 bytes

Tags: python, struct, pickle, pyzmq, unpack

I am using zmq to pass messages back and forth from a client/server. I am using pickle to deserialze the message, so I can parse information out of it. When I am sending a message that is less than 256 bytes, everything works as expected, and I can grab the message ID from the 12 byte. However, if I send a message with a buffer length of more than 255 bytes, struct.pack_into doesn't seem the be reading the fields correctly, and is giving the wrong messageID. I printed out the bytes, and they are still sending correctly. It seems like struct.pack_into can no longer properly find the 12th byte. Somehow the size is changing its behavior. Suggestions?

Client:

```
buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(256)
struct.pack_into("!qII", buf, 0, message.Timestamp, message.MessageID, message.Payload)
# Send reply back to client with version
socket.send(buf)
```

Server:

```
message = socket.recv()
message = pickle.dumps(message)  # Serializes object

(timestamp, message_ID) = struct.unpack_from('!qi', message, 4)  # Start reading on 4th byte (pickle adds header)
```

Comment: Why in the world are you using `pickle` here?  The output of `pickle.dumps()` has no conceivable use other than being passed to `pickle.loads()` later - it might make sense on the sending end, but on the receiving end it's simply insane.

Comment: I have no idea, for some reason I thought I had to serialize it. I did try without using it, and it appears to be working. Ill get rid of it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> **Q :**  *<sub>Suggestions?</sub>*

Just follow the `struct` documented properties.

Current code fails on both loading data into `struct.pack()` and keeps trying to unload some other data layout in `struct.unpack_from()`, than was used for the `struct`-payload assembly.

```
struct.pack_into( "!qII", ################## Use this packing LAYOUT !:: BIG_ENDIAN byte-ordering ( "network"-alike )
                        buf,               # ----BUFFER[256]         q:: (  signed ) long long 8-B  ~  int64
                        0,                 # ----start_at_offset 0   I::  unsigned         int 4-B  ~ uint32
                        message.Timestamp, # ----a------+            I::  unsigned         int 4-B  ~ uint32
                        message.MessageID, # ----b------:---------------+
                        message.Payload    # ----c------:---------------:-------+     <End-of-STORAGE-FORMAT>
                  )                        #          |_:____________+8_:____+4_:____+4
                                           # Big      | v             |  v    | v     |
#                                          # ENDIAN   |0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7|8.9.A.B|C.D.E.F|
#                                          #                                  ?in just|
#      Send reply back to client w version #                                  ?4-Bytes|
socket.send( buf )                         # if len( message.Payload ) > 4 ...^^^.^^^^^ Houston, we have a problem ...
#     |
#     |
#     V
#-----V-------- network-transported payload
#     V
```

---

```
#     :
#     :
#     :
#-----V-------- network-delivered (same) payload
#     V
socket.recv()

( timestamp,
  message_ID
  ) = struct.unpack_from( '!qi', ########### Use this packing LAYOUT !:: BIG_ENDIAN byte-ordering ( "network"-alike )
                               message,    # ----PAYLOAD-DATA        q:: (  signed ) long long 8-B  ~  int64
                               4           # ----from_offset 4!      I::  unsigned         int 4-B  ~ uint32
                          )                #                  !
#                                          # MESSAGE  |_______!_______________________<End-of-STORAGE-FORMAT>
#                                          # DATA     |       !                       |
#                                          #          |0.1.2.3!4.5.6.7.8.9.A.B.C.D.E.F|
#                                                             |              +8      +4
#                                                             |               |       |
#                                                             |0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7|8.9.A.B|
#                                                             :               :       <End-of-UNPACK-FORMAT>
#( timestamp <----------------------------------------------<-:_______________:       :
#  message_ID <-------------------------------------------------------------<-:_______:
#  )
```

So,
unless there is some hidden intent to somehow cross-breed a mix of bytes, taking the last-4-bytes from the original, sending Python **`int64`**-8B-long-long `message.Timestamp` & joining them with the **`uint32`**-4-bytes from the original, sending Python `message.MessageID` to *decode* a receiving-side Python a new **`int64`**-8B-long-long, formed from this mix, stored into a python `( timestamp, ... )` first item, leaving the rest ( 4B-long part of the delivered payload (originated as a `message.Payload` in the sending Python side) to now get decoded & stored as `( ..., message_ID )`,
we
will have to repair the code, to at least avoid the current Byte-cross-breeding.

So, either use the very same `struct`-format-string-TEMPLATES on either side, or one may design an adaptive data-storage layout compositions, where the `PAYLOAD`-assembler puts the correct byte-length into a known, fix position (best coded as the first `I`-uint32, or a `10s`-string representation, if an easy, human-readable, wireline packet inspection is wished to be kept)

The `PAYLOAD`-receiver will then first decode the `PAYLOAD`-data on this known, fix, position -- so as to learn the actual whole `PAYLOAD`-length from it -- and as a second step it will adaptively compose the learned length-"matching" format-string-TEMPLATE :

```
...
TEMPLATE_MASK = "!10s I I {0:}s"
...
aRecvdMSG = socket.recv()

TEMPLATE = TEMPLATE_MASK.format( int( struct.unpack( "!10s", aRecvdMSG )[0] )
                               -10  # SUB _10s_ for _str__  used for advice of payload length
                               - 4  # SUB ___I_ for _int32_ used for ...
                               - 4  # SUB ___I_ for _int32_ used for ID
                                 )
...
( aPayloadByteLENGTH,
  aVersionNUM,
  aMessageID,
  ) = struct.unpack( TEMPLATE, aRecvdMSG )
```

The same principle applies to the sending Python side, where `PAYLOAD`-assembly can use the very same adaptively composed `TEMPLATE.format(...)`-method, so as the `struct.pack()`-method gets all details in-order & well aligned, so as to avoid both any kind of the declared buffer-overflows and any kind of mixing bytes in order/alignment-related "cross-breeding" ill-demapped bytes from the delivered `PAYLOAD`-content into the hands of the blind & believing receiving-side Python interpreter.

Having used this for more than a decade for many-items long message-`PAYLOAD` assembly/dissasembly in low-latency TAT [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) systems, you can rely on re-using this know how for any less demanding data-portability guaranteed ZeroMQ-served communication DATA-interexchange